# Is there a reason to not create your own navigation stack in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, customization

In a project I am working with in Swift, I have a huge form that needs to be filled out. I found the best way to present the form was by combining many table views in a Modal Popover that takes over 75%ish of the screen. Using animation and a custom build Array of ViewControllers, I created something very similar to a Navigation Stack that never kept any views in it if they were data intensive by keeping them at the top or second to the top of the stack. It would push them onto the left or right side of the modal, all being done with a simple one liner outside of the Container Controller. Is this implementation bad to use for any reason?  I feel like I might have bypassed a natural way of making this work without realizing it was an option.

My skills in Swift have been skyrocketing since I left my college in December, but I don't work directly with anyone more knowledgeable than me in Swift. This makes some of the more complex questions hard to answer without intense amounts of research. (which I am not opposed to if I can find an answer) I am expected to provide a quality working product in the end though, so I need to be assured that I am not making any mistakes that are at the backbone of my project.

Comment: I don't think this is so much a language-question as a platform-question. I would say _generally_ reimplementing that more or less mimic functionality already available through Apple's API's is not a good thing. It is also likely to make a sub-optimal user-experience if things behaves _almost_ (but not quite) like the users expect from the platform.

Comment: I like the answer, but I feel it isn't fully applicable here because I am not using segues. Without segues I can't use the Navigation Stack like I normally would be able to, unless I am missing something. If that is the case, then telling me that would answer my question.

Comment: Of course you can use the navigation stack without segues. You just push and pop viewControllers on the navigation-stack.

Comment: Is using the navigation stack in that manner considered completely fine in practice?

Comment: Yes, it is probably the most common pattern, especially for larger apps not relying on storyboards.

Comment: Thank you, I started with swift and storyboarding, so I am just getting deep in the finer details of things like that.